# Pandas: Getting average of columns and rows with crosstab

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataframe (sample of it atleast)

```
DATETIME_FROM               DATETIME_TO             MEAS    ROW VEHICLE SPEED
1   2020-02-27 05:19:42.750 2020-02-27 05:20:42.750 2.2844  1   26  85
2   2020-02-27 05:30:06.050 2020-02-27 05:31:06.050 2.5256  1   31  69
3   2020-02-27 05:36:02.370 2020-02-27 05:37:02.370 4.8933  1   37  86
4   2020-02-27 05:41:12.005 2020-02-27 05:42:12.005 2.6998  1   27  86
5   2020-02-27 05:46:30.773 2020-02-27 05:47:30.773 2.2720  1   26  86
6   2020-02-27 05:50:53.862 2020-02-27 05:51:53.862 4.6953  1   3   82
7   2020-02-27 05:59:45.381 2020-02-27 06:00:45.381 2.5942  1   31  86
8   2020-02-27 06:04:12.657 2020-02-27 06:05:12.657 4.9136  1   37  86
```

The results should be a table, where I get mean average of every vehicle, each day.
but I would also like to have a total mean of MEAS per day, and per vehicle

[image]

[image]

I am using this:

```
pd.crosstab([valid1low.DATE,valid1low.ROW], [valid1low.VEHICLE], values=valid1low.MEAS, aggfunc=[np.mean], margins=True)
```

And the total looks like an average, but if I use Excel to make the average, I don't get the same result.

Could this be because Excel is not using the same precision of MEAS values?
and how would I get the same result?

The end user of this table will be using excel, so if the total average differs from excel, I would get questions :)

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are looking for if I understand correctly is [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). I have tried to recreate a similar dataframe with the code below to explain.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['DATETIME_FROM'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({'year': [2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                   'month': [2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2],
                   'day': [27, 27, 27, 27,28,28,28,28],
                    'hour':[24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38],
                    'minute':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16],
                     'second':[1,3,5,7,8,10,12,13]                              }))
df['DATETIME_TO'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({'year': [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020,2020,2020,2020,2020],
                   'month': [2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2],
                   'day': [27, 27, 27, 27,28,28,28,28],
                   'hour':[25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39],
                   'minute':[3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17],
                   'second':[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]
                   }))
df['MEAS'] = [ 2.2844,2.5256,4.8933,2.6998,1,2,3,4]
df['ROW'] = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
df['VEHICLE'] = [26,31,37,27,65,46,45,49]
df['VEHICLE_SPEED'] =[85,69,86,86,90,91,92,93]
```

The dataframe that this code creates looks like the following.

```
        DATETIME_FROM         DATETIME_TO    MEAS  ROW  VEHICLE  VEHICLE_SPEED
0 2020-02-28 00:02:01 2020-02-28 01:03:02  2.2844    1       26             85
1 2020-02-28 02:04:03 2020-02-28 03:05:04  2.5256    1       31             69
2 2020-02-28 04:06:05 2020-02-28 05:07:06  4.8933    1       37             86
3 2020-02-28 06:08:07 2020-02-28 07:09:08  2.6998    1       27             86
4 2020-02-29 08:10:08 2020-02-29 09:11:10  1.0000    2       65             90
5 2020-02-29 10:12:10 2020-02-29 11:13:12  2.0000    2       46             91
6 2020-02-29 12:14:12 2020-02-29 13:15:14  3.0000    2       45             92
7 2020-02-29 14:16:13 2020-02-29 15:17:16  4.0000    2       49             93
```

You said that you need to get the mean of each vehicle per day and the mean of the MEAS per day. So I grouped by the day using the groupby function along with the [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to specify the day as the target to group by within the `DATETIME_FROM` column. Then I just got the mean of all the rows for a given column using the [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) function. This function sums up the values in a given column and divides it by the number of rows.

```
means = df.set_index(["DATETIME_FROM"]).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean()
```

The dataframe `means` now contains the following. The `DATEIME_FROM` is now the index as we have grouped by this column.

```
                  MEAS  ROW  VEHICLE  VEHICLE_SPEED
DATETIME_FROM                                       
2020-02-27     3.100775  1.0    30.25           81.5
2020-02-28     2.500000  2.0    51.25           91.5
```

When you say you want the total means of MEAS and vehicle I am assuming that you want the mean of the values for the columns in the `mean` dataframe. This can be done by just getting the means of these columns, I then just created a new dataframe called `totals` and added these entrys.

```
mean_meas =means['MEAS'].mean()
mean_vechicles = means['VEHICLE'].mean()
total = pd.DataFrame({'MEAN MEAS':[mean_meas],'MEAN VECHICLE':[mean_vechicles]})
```

The totals dataframe then will include the following:

```
   MEAN MEAS  MEAN VECHICLE
0   2.800388          40.75
```

I hope this helps, if you have a question let me know!

Comment: Hi,
I added a picture to better illustrate, I guess the table is unreadable.

So I want the average of each individual vehicle, and a column and a row. where I get the average of all vehicles, for each day, and average for same vehicle for total time

Comment: I am still a little confused on this, is the vehicle column a vehicle ID and can it appear on multiple different days or is it a count for the number of vehicles in that day?

Comment: Vehicle is a vehicle ID yes.
Each vehicle gives a measurement several times a day.
I am then using crosstab to determine the mean average every single day for each vehicle.

But I also want to have the mean average of each vehicle during the whole timeperiod.
also, a mean average of all vehicles each day.